# Ubuntu Android Shared Folders

Tags: android, shared-folders, mediaserver

I have installed samba on ubuntu and shared a folder by right clicking on it and sharing it from it sharing option.

I have an app on Android that manages the files and it asks me for IP Adress and the shared folder.

However I cannot find my IP Address on ubuntu that can make connection to other devices

I used to do this in Windows CMD

```
ipconfig
```

and then every things showed up
but I cannot find it on Ubuntu .

I just need a way to make connection between them through nautilas.

Answer (score 0):

This is way way old...but still is at the top of the Google search results for Android/Ubuntu shared folders.

Use ifconfig on the command line. That will give you the info you need.